# MYSQL add row with id=first bank AND that does not exist on another table

Tags: mysql, select

With this 2 tables:

```
table1
----
id(ai) id_aaa 
 1      1  
 31     2
 32     3
 43     5
 46     8

table2
----
id record
 1   4
```

I need a select that gives me table1 id_aaa=6. Next available id aaa that does not exist as record in table2.

Comment: `table1 id_aaa=7`? Doesn't make sense. Thats not the next available id.

Comment: You are right, its id_aaa=6, im sorry. Ill edit my original post

Comment: Which field do you want to check with in table2? `id` or `record`? And please show what you have tried.

Comment: i want to check with record

Comment: This sounds like an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT MIN(id_aaa + 1) AS next_one FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table1 t1bis ON t1.id_aaa + 1 = t1bis.id_aaa 
WHERE t1bis.id_aaa IS NULL AND id_aaa + 1 NOT IN (SELECT record FROM table2);
```

Comment: can you post your solution and check it then? :)